# Override li style with class

Tags: css, overriding, html-lists

in my site I created this html/css

```
li
{
    float: left;
    ...
}

.myclass
{
    float: right;
    ...
}

<ul>
    <li>test 1</li>
    <li class="myclass">test 2</li>
</ul>
```

The two list elements have the same style but the second doesn't use the class to override the left float. Why?

**EDIT:**
it seems that if I use

```
li.myclass
{
    float: right;
    ...
}
```

it works but I'm using myclass also in divs because it's a common style class. How can I fix the problem without use li.?

Comment: The question is, what are you trying to accomplish? If you want to have the list items side by side, just use display:inline

Comment: @Dan I edited my question with one more info. I'm trying to align a li element right and all the others left

Comment: It works for me in Firefox6 and IE8. What browser are you testing in?

Comment: @Anson solved, anyway I was testing it in firefox 7.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your post says, you're able to overwrite the `float`-property if you use a more "specific" selector, such as `li.myclass`. So you could list the two selectors in a comma-seperated list.

```
.myclass, li.myclass {
    float: right;
}
```

Or you can use `!important` to overwrite the property.

```
.myclass {
    float: right !important;
}
```

Also, it plays a role at which position in your CSS the property shows up. Properties that are located lower in the file can overwrite properties which are above.

Comment: I will use your first solution

Answer (score 0):

Coming from your comment, I think you should use a table, as it seems pretty much like becoming one. Tables are not evil as long as they aren't getting used to to design-work.

Or if you really want to avoid tables, just do two lists and align the 's with float.